# Adding values in web config dynamically? How To + Best way

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

i just came up with the reading, Writing and adding values dynamically in web.Config in asp.net. Have many ideas in mind, but i just wana know what is the best way of adding values in web config dynamically.

for example in my case i have to add

```
 <identity  userName="someDomain\User" password="password" impersonate="true" />
```

in

tag in web config from code behind.

waiting for Good responses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got you and the code you want is :

```
 public void saveIdentity(string username, string password, bool impersonate)
    {
        Configuration objConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        IdentitySection identitySection = (IdentitySection)objConfig.GetSection("system.web/identity");
        if (identitySection != null)
        {
            identitySection.UserName = username;
            identitySection.Password = password;
            identitySection.Impersonate = impersonate;
        }
    objConfig.Save();
}
```

Comment: for anyone who is having trouble getting this to work, keep in mind your application pool has to run under the "Local System" identity for it to to be able to modify the file sytem.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to don't try to update web.config dynamically. By doing so your application will be restart and your user session will be expired.

by doing changes in the following your application will always restart

```
* web.config
* machine.config
* global.asax
* Anything in the bin directory or it's sub-directories
```

for details have a look [aspnet-application-restarts.html](http://fuchangmiao.blogspot.com/2007/11/aspnet-application-restarts.html)

Comment: @Akhtar: i m aware of that fact, and user's session is not a issue at my end =)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to set the identity in code?  This is usually something that should be set up front when the app is deployed and then left alone.  If you can explain what you are trying to accomplish we can likely suggest a better way to do it.

Aside from that are you aware that changing your web config will cause the app to restart?  All of your server side caching will get dumped, user sessions will be ended, etc.  Just because the tool exists to modify the web config from code does not mean doing so is a good idea.

Comment: i know that all, i have a case in what i have to add this from code side.

Comment: Well in that case I am afraid I don’t have any real suggestions for you. Everything I know says don’t do this. It is akin to using a sledge hammer to drive a nail, it might get the job done but it is also likely to break something in the process.  I would be interested to see if someone comes up with a decent way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

This is in the desktop application but we can use it in web application

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(txtPortNumber.Text.Trim()) <= 65535)
{

    System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSection = config.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup;

    mailSection.Smtp.From = txtFrom.Text.Trim();
    mailSection.Smtp.Network.Host = txtFrom.Text.Trim();
    mailSection.Smtp.Network.UserName = txtFrom.Text.Trim();
    mailSection.Smtp.Network.Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
    mailSection.Smtp.Network.EnableSsl = chkEnableSSL.Checked;
    mailSection.Smtp.Network.Port = Convert.ToInt32(txtPortNumber.Text.Trim());
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    MessageBox.Show("Your mail setting has been saved successfully.");
    Application.Restart();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Port number is not valid, please enter port number between the 0 to 65535.");
}
```