# Is there anything wrong with modifying the web.config file dynamically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I read [this](http://www.codecapers.com/post/MVC%E2%80%93Showing-a-setup-screen-on-the-first-run.aspx) article. I was planning on creating a setup page that runs and allows the user to change the sql connection strings which is stored in the web.config file. With some changes this may help in deployment or even development. My question is is it possible to change the connection string in the web.config file based on user input and is this advisable. N.B The connection string must be contained in the web.config

THank you

Comment: Check this similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324924/adding-values-in-web-config-dynamically-how-to-best-way/5325191#5325191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find helpful [this](http://www.polemus.net/2010/09/add-connectionstring-to-webconfig.html) blogpost on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

hmmmm. Changing the web.config file would cause the app to restart. At least that's what would normally happen and from my understanding of the dependencies involved would happen if you did it from code.

That might be acceptable to you though & it is the best way to do it if the restart is acceptable.

Simon

Comment: Restarting will only occur once based on this http://www.codecapers.com/post/MVC%E2%80%93Showing-a-setup-screen-on-the-first-run.aspx

Comment: That post addresses dealing with an first time start. Other posts are saying what I said - Changing the web.config will cause the application to restart.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to modify web.config based upon user input.  It's just an XML file.

We do this as part of a custom action in an installer (MSI).

Modifying a web.config will cause the application pool to recycle though.  Depending on your site, this (recycling) may or may not be a big deal.